# How do Templates/monsters stack?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, monsters

I was thinking of various monsters from popular fiction (specifically the 5 nights at freddy's robots), and I wondered. is it possible to have an undead construct? How do templates work in the game? and how does it affect CR?

Comment: Specifically for the FNAF creatures: Most constructs are, lorewise, the combination of an artifically built nonliving body with a spirit/elemental/soul forcefully bound to it. In this case the tormented spirits of murdered kids are bound to (or posessing) the animatronic robots.

Comment: Well, I guess I thought undead because of the ghosts and turning. I didn't know the bit of lore that it's attached to a soul. I thought a construct=robot. Though it is never in FNaF, I imagine if a DnD Character met them (or a similar story) that a last minute turning that keeps them away gave them the time to find out the story of the souls, and then avenge them. Of course though pathfinder screws that up by removing turning with the more mechanically helpful energy

Comment: Have you done any research, mate?

Comment: Well, it's not in the pathfinder core rulebook. I've read the core rulebook, but not pathfinder expansions other than that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Construct and Undead are types, not templates.  A creature can only have one type, though it may have its previous types as subtypes.  So an 'undead construct' of the kind you are talking about would probably be type Undead(Augmented Construct).  This means they are functionally undead and not constructs, despite having been constructs in the past.  What exactly happens depends on the template you use to turn the Construct undead.  This template would need to be homebrewed because there are no existing templates that convert constructs into undead.

Templates stack.  After each template, you have a new monster, which you could then apply an additional template to.  You must apply them in an order, and that order usually matters a lot.  Some combinations may only be possible with a certain order, because of prerequisites. For example, you can have a Half-Fiend Half-Dragon Half-Celestial, but not a Half-Dragon Half-Celestial Half-Fiend.

CR adjustments are listed with templates.  They also stack.  CR is not a good measurement of power, and this will require adjudication as to the appropriate CR of the finished creature if you want it to be a more useful metric.

Comment: Did pathfinder implement the type pyramid?

Comment: @fectin what's a type pyramid?

Comment: Savage Species defined an order of precedence for types. It actually worked well.

Comment: @fectin Oh, okay.  No, Pathfinder didn't implement that, and it technically wouldn't forward-port by RAW since that text contradicts the MM which is the primary source on templates.  It's cool that the system actually works out, though!

Comment: It's more specific. MM just tells you to apply changes. SS says do not apply changes under X circumstances.